# How to extract the results on the same workbooks as the command button?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract the results of my CheckTables codes on the worksheets Book3. However, since the command button is on Book3.xlsm, I got an error message that it couldn't extract the output because Book3.xlsm is already opened, when I was trying to run the following codes. Is there any way that I could get the result on the same workbook as my command button? Thanks a lot!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set myWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\docs\Book1.xlsx")
Set myWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\docs\Book2.xlsx")
Set myWorkbook3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\docs\Book3.xlsm")

CheckTables myWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1"), myWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1"), myWorkbook3.Worksheets("Sheet1")
CheckTables myWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet2"), myWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet2"), myWorkbook3.Worksheets("Sheet2")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Set myWorkbook3 = ThisWorkbook
```

To be honest, though, you wouldn't need to set it as an object in this instance; it already is one.

Just use ThisWorkbook. where you'd normally be using myWorkbook3.